# Send bigger amount of data

Tags: c, sockets

I am working with sockets in **C** (linux) and I need to send a bit longer text (60characters) over the network. I've tried a char pointer, but it is too short. Any suggestions what should I use?

```
char *data = "A lot of text....";
...
if (send(new_fd, data, 13, 0) == -1)
            perror("send");
```

I'm not really a `c` person, so what does that number `13` mean?

Comment: Please show us the code that you're using.

Comment: Please show your try. Where do your approach faild?

Comment: Some context might be helpful here :)

Comment: a char pointer, or any pointer, can't be "short", they are just pointing to memory somewhere. Post your code so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you should send the data.

```
char *data = "A lot of text....";
ssize_t rc;
...
rc = send(new_fd, data, strlen(data), 0);
/* Check rc. */
```

From [the manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html):

```
ssize_t send(int socket, const void *buffer, size_t length, int flags);
```

So the `13` is the number of bytes sent.

One thing to consider is that `send(2)` doesn't guarantee it will be able to send all of it in one go. You need to loop and check how much it wrote. A good way to do it is using the [`writen` function](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs779/stevens2nd/lib/writen.c) of Stevens.

Comment: could you please comment more on this code? thanks a lot

Comment: @shaggy I edited it to fit your question beter.

Comment: @cnicutar: note that `ssize_t` may not be the same as `int`. I suggest you use the former.

Comment: &cnicutar thanks! and what is the difference if i just change that `13` to `100` for example, and if i use your code?

Comment: @shaggy Read the manual page. The third argument is **the number of bytes sent**.

Comment: @cnicutar im sorry, missunderstanding. thanks!

Comment: one more thing, right after i create this `char *data;` i get some strange chars in that : `�(���Ũ` . Afterwards im doing a `strcat()` and those strange chars stays there anyway..do you have an idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @shaggy Show the code (including the strcat and whatnot).

Comment: `char *data;
add_data(data, table);

void add_data(char *data, struct ARP_entry *table)
{
  strcat(data, table[0].IPaddr); 
}`

Comment: @shaggy You need to allocate memory for `data` (using `malloc`).